# How do I replace text in excel using powershell

Tags: excel, replace

Working on writing a script that will replace content in excel file.

I have the following script written, but I can not seem to get it to processed without user input.  This is to automate a process, thus user input is not required.

**region**

```
#launch excel   
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application

#call file
$FilePath = "C:\AESOP\emp.xlsx"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)


$WorkSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$range = $worksheet.range("D:D").entirecolumn 
$range.Columns.Replace("A","Y") 
$range.Columns.Replace("I","N") 
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1,4) = 'Active'


$WorkSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$range = $worksheet.range("F:F").entirecolumn 

$range.Columns.Replace("ACCOUNT CLERK I","Secretarial Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("ACCOUNT CLERK II","Secretarial Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("ASSISTANT COACH - CLASSIFIED","Other")
$range.Columns.Replace("ASSISTANT COACH - PARA","Other")
$range.Columns.Replace("ASSISTANT COACH-XDUTY","Other")
$range.Columns.Replace("BUS AIDE - EXCEPTIONAL CHILD","Transportation Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("BUS DRIVER","Transportation Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("BUS DRIVER TRAINING ASSISTANT","Transportation Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("BUS DRIVER TRNING COORDINATOR","Transportation Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("BUS MONITOR","Transportation Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("CERTIFIED SOCIAL WORKER","Teacher/Professional Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("CERTIFIED STAFF","Teacher/Professional Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("CHIEF INFORMATION OFFICER","Technology Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("CHILD DEVELOP CENTER ASST SUPR","Other")
$range.Columns.Replace("CHILD DEVELOPMENT CENTER SUPRV","Other")
$range.Columns.Replace("COMPUTER ENGINEER","Technology Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("COMPUTER LAB TECHNICIAN","Technology Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("COOK/BAKER","Cafeteria Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("COORDINATOR I","Other")
$range.Columns.Replace("CUSTODIAL SUPERVISOR","Facilities Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("CUSTODIAN","Facilities Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("DAYCARE ASST - HRLY","Secretarial Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("DEAN OF STUDENTS","Teacher/Professional Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("DELIVERY DRIVER","Transportation Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("DIR OF DISTRIC PERSONNEL","Teacher/Professional Staff")
$range.Columns.Replace("DIRECTOR III","Other")




#save as csv
$SavePath = "C:\AESOP\emp2.xlsx" 
$workbook.saveas($SavePath)
#$workbook.close


$excel.quit() 
Write-Host "Closed Excel"
Get-Process excel | Stop-Process -Force
```

**endregion**

Comment: Is the `$workbook.close` prompting you to save changes?

Comment: I get prompt for the replace.    "We couldn't find anything to replace. Click options for more ways to search"

Comment: Potential side problem. Using the first two `Replace` lines as an example. Replacing `"ACCOUNT CLERK I"` will change `"ACCOUNT CLERK II"` to `"Secretarial StaffI`. You probably want to specify more parameters for [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.replace?view=excel-pia).

Comment: I am new at powershell, thus I am unsure how to have it replace on the exact match, what parameters would i need to use?  I am not sure that the code I am using is the easiest, just what I have been able to get working thus far.

Comment: The *LookAt* parameter (3rd), see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.replace?view=excel-pia). Guessing you want `1`, which corresponds to [`xlWhole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xllookat?view=excel-pia).